# Remove the '\' from a string in twig

Tags: symfony, twig, twig-extension, twig-filter

I have this text :

```
Ch d\`Arnb
```

Now I want to remove all `\` from string if exist. I try a lot of solutions, one of this : `{{ item|replace({'\/': ''}) }}`. But without success. What can I try next?

Answer (score 11):

There is an error in the replace parameter. You are presently trying to remove the `/` char. Try this:

```
{% set item = 'Foo\Bar' %}

{{ item|replace({'\\': ''}) }}
```

Output: `FooBar`